# Kotlin coroutines: how to detect if we are already in suspending context?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a function that is called from a blocking function, and it launches several coroutines in parallel and collects results. As such, it begins with `runBlocking`.

But there is a lot of advice to never ever invoke `runBlocking` inside a coroutine. So I'd like my function to throw an `IllegalStateException` if my function is invoked from a suspending one. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Interesting question. My gut feeling is there is no reliable and straightforward way to do this. If we control fully what dispatchers do we use across our code, we can check if the thread is one controlled by one of "our" dispatchers. We can try to use a `ThreadLocal.asContextElement()`. Even more hacky solution: get a stack trace and see if we run inside the coroutines machinery. But no, I don't see an easy way.

Comment: maybe you should not use runBlocking, or take out the runBlocking to the call site, but other than that, the question is really interesting

Comment: After you have used runBlocking, the function is not really any different than any other blocking function. You just have to document it as a blocking function. The person writing suspend functions and coroutines is responsible for checking function documentation to make sure they aren’t calling blocking functions. The only thing the compiler checks is whether the function throws IOExceptions and it warns you if it does and you use it in a suspending context without the IO dispatcher. It’s not a perfect system but there is a high correlation between functions that throw IOException and block.

Comment: So as a hack you could maybe use `@Throws(IOException::class)`.